# Access output of layers inside Core ML Model

Tags: swift, caffe, coreml, coremltools

I used the Core ML Converter to convert a Caffe AlexNet model to a Core ML model. The model works just fine and outputs correct classification results. However, I do not know how to access the output of a layer inside the CNN model. Say for example I want to know what the output of one of the convolution layer (e.g. conv5) is. Caffe let you do so easily, but I could not find documentation on how to do this using Core ML.

Does Core ML allow access to outputs of layers inside the CNN model like Caffe does?

Comment: I don't think that you can, unless you've somehow defined custom layers for each of the CNN's layers.

Comment: @NRitH How do you mean defining custom layers? Can I still use trained weights from '.caffemodel' file?

Comment: Because your converted CoreML model gives you the same results as the Caffe one, each of the Caffe's layers correspond to layer types that already exist in CoreML. You could probably add custom layers (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/core_ml_api/integrating_custom_layers), but then you'd have to implement them yourself.

Comment: It appears that you can modify the .prototxt file associated with the Caffe model to remove layers and then rebuild the model.   So, worst case you could make separate models to access the layers of interest.  But I'm still hoping there is some way through the model API to access them.